# How to change the text of HTML without changing the structure of it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to do the following: in a HTML-file I want to replace all of the words "bee" (say) through "fly". But all of the structure of HTML muss remain the same. I do this with BeautifulSoup (the code follows):

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


with open(file, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    source = f.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
for tag in soup:
    if type(tag) is not bs4.element.Tag:
        continue
    new_soup = BeautifulSoup(str(tag).replace('bee', 'fly'))
    tag.replace_with(new_soup)
with open(file_out, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

The problem is: the replacement works fine, but the structure of the file becomes ugly (the paragraphs are then from some point in the file merged together so I have solid text without blank lines etc.) And if I look in the HTML-code of the file I see that the structure is now completely different (I have f.e. suddenly some "html"-tags where I hadn't any and so on).

How can I replace the words in the text of HTML without loosing the HTML-structure?

Thanks in advance, Denis

Comment: You don't lose the structure, you lose the formatting.

Comment: OK, that is what I mean then. But I don't want to lose it. So the question ist how I can retain it.

Comment: source is a string so you can try `source = source.replace('bee', 'fly')` but it can also replace `been` with `flyn`, etc. To keep format you have to use string function or regex instead of `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Instead of writing `str(soup)`, you could try [`soup.prettify()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing) instead. This would still restructure your HTML but it would be to a good standard.